# How to implement a collapsing header in Android with Motion Layout using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I was curious and try to implement a similar UI like playstore, When I try to implement collapsing header with searchbar, I can't get exact code or document that I was looking for in Jetpack compose.

This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

Currently in my implementation, I have a ParentScreen, which contains the Searchbar view and tabview with horizontal viewPager. That tab contains two screens "HomeScreen and Menu Screen"

In Homescreen, it has a LazyColumn, when user scroll through the lazyColumn in HomeScreen, I want to achieve this Behaviour of hide/show of searchview which was in ParentScreen.

Can I achieve this by using Motionlayout or anyother type of animations in Jetpack compose?
Any help would be Thankfull!

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1:**

If your header can fit into a `TopAppBar`, you can use `TopAppBar` with `enterAlwaysScrollBehavior`. See documentation on [Top app bars](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/app-bars#top-bar).

[image: Screen recording]

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun CollapsingTopAppBar() {
    val listItems = buildList { repeat(100) { add(it) } }
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text("Search bar") },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        },
    ) { paddingValues ->
        var tab by rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(paddingValues)
        ) {
            TabRow(selectedTabIndex = tab) {
                Tab(selected = true, onClick = { tab = 0 }) { Text("Tab 0") }
                Tab(selected = false, onClick = { tab = 1 }) { Text("Tab 1") }
                Tab(selected = false, onClick = { tab = 2 }) { Text("Tab 2") }
            }
            LazyColumn {
                items(items = listItems, key = { it }) {
                    Text(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp).fillMaxWidth(), text = "Item $it")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

If using `TopAppBar` is not an option, you can use [nested scroll](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).nestedScroll(androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection,androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollDispatcher)) functionality. There is a collapsing toolbar example at the link above, and below is a modified example that behaves more like the layout in the question.

```
@Composable
fun CollapsingHeader() {
    val density = LocalDensity.current

    var headerSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize(0, 0)) }
    val headerHeight by remember(headerSize) { mutableStateOf(with(density) { headerSize.height.toDp() }) }

    var tabsSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize(0, 0)) }
    val tabsHeight by remember(tabsSize) { mutableStateOf(with(density) { tabsSize.height.toDp() }) }

    val headerOffsetHeightPx = remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    val nestedScrollConnection = remember(headerSize) {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            val headerHeightPx = headerSize.height.toFloat()

            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                val delta = available.y
                val newOffset = headerOffsetHeightPx.floatValue + delta
                headerOffsetHeightPx.floatValue = newOffset.coerceIn(-headerHeightPx, 0f)
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                // Set zIndex to appear above LazyColumn. Alternatively, put LazyColumn above this Column
                .zIndex(1f)
                .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = headerOffsetHeightPx.floatValue.roundToInt()) }
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface),
        ) {
            // Collapsable top composable
            Header(modifier = Modifier.onSizeChanged { headerSize = it })
            // Composable that will take top of the screen when the list is scrolled up
            Tabs(modifier = Modifier.onSizeChanged { tabsSize = it })
        }
        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = headerHeight + tabsHeight)
        ) {
            items(100) { index ->
                Text(
                    text = "Item $index",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Header(
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        Text("Collapsing header")
        Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            OutlinedTextField(value = "", onValueChange = {})
            Button(onClick = {}) { Text("Search") }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Tabs(
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        Text("Something")
        TabRow(selectedTabIndex = 0) {
            Tab(selected = true, onClick = {}) { Text("Tab 0") }
            Tab(selected = false, onClick = {}) { Text("Tab 1") }
            Tab(selected = false, onClick = {}) { Text("Tab 2") }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it may work when use with TopAppbar, but for searchbar , I have used Box with column and TextField, so for that it may not work. Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I've added another implementation to my answer. @Sanjay